# Aptana close files after "search in files"

Tags: aptana3

It's an annoying problem in Aptana. If you make a search in files, click on a result, a file open. Then, you make another search and click in a new result file. The previous opened file is closed!

It's possible to disable this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On the search panel there is a little inverted triangle for options (up right corner).

Click there and choose "Preferences".

Uncheck the option "Reuse editors to show matches".

That's it.

Answer (score 0):

For version 3.4.2 (latest version as of today):

On a mac, Click on **Aptana Studio 3** in the Taskbar

Click on "Preferences"

Under "General" click on "Search" and then you will be able to uncheck the "Reuse editors to show matches"